# How to get selected text of a particular button in table view in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here I used a radio button for selecting in a list here when I select a particular radio button then I need to pass the corresponding text in the label for shipping method which is corresponding to radio button can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Here is the image for this

[image]

here is the code for the selected button in table view

```
func paymentRadioAction(button : KGRadioButton) {
        _ = button.center
        let centralPoint = button.superview?.convert(button.center, to:self.shippingTableView)
        let indexPath =  self.shippingTableView.indexPathForRow(at: centralPoint!)
        if button.isSelected {

        } else{
            chekIndex = indexPath
            radioSelection = true
            checkIndex = chekIndex
            self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
            self.boolDelegate?.boolvalidation(bool: radioSelection!)
            radioSelection = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hope this will help... on button action let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath); let labelText = cell.labelName.text

Comment: if I need to get section name for the selection section then how to get ? @Bapu

Comment: You can get it by indexPath.section.Suppose u have an array which contains section names.on your button action:- let sectionName = yourArrayName[indexPath.section]. let me know ur feedback

Comment: Working thanks bro @Bapu